# Standard deviation for categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I have desperately been trying to work this out and have referred to several posts but am still not getting the correct answer!

I have a bunch of providers of different provider type. I calculate an average cost change for each provider (from more granular payment data). I then want to find the standard deviation of these provider level changes for the difference provider type.

This is where I've got up to with the dax - this gives the same standard deviation across all provider types rather than the required output.

```
group_test = 
var tab1 = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(ProvData[Provider Type],ProvData[Provider Code], "prov_avg",AVERAGEX(core_data, sum(PayData[Payment1])-sum(PayData[Payment2]))/SUM(PayData[Payment1]))    
var sd_type = SELECTCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE(tab1,[Provider Type],[Provider Code], "test", STDEVX.S(tab1,[prov_avg])), "sd_type", [test])
var tab2 =  ADDCOLUMNS(tab1, "sd_type", sd_type)
return tab2
```

I want my final table to look like this

| Provider Code | Provider type | Prov_avg | sd_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x | sd for a |
| 2 | a | y | sd for a |
| 3 | b | z | sd for b |

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Perhaps a very small data sample with expected results would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your table:

```
stdColumn = 
var prov_Code = ProvData[Provider Code]
var prov_type = ProvData[Provider Type]
var stdValue = CALCULATE (STDEV.S([prov_avg]), FILTER(prov_Code = ProvData[Provider Code] && prov_type = ProvData[Provider Type]))
return stdValue
```

So what we do is to calculate the stdev based on the filter given on Code & Type